# ProgressBar setProgress() not working after Activity recreate()

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, activity-lifecycle, recreate

I have a horizontal `ProgressBar` which is displaying the remaining life in a game. When the life is 0 (`ProgressBar` progress is 0) the game ends and there is a button RESTART which calls to `activity.recreate();`. The progress must be shown full again when recreating but it's being shown empty (progress 0).

All is working fine and being recreated correctly but the `ProgressBar`. The onCreate() method has this lines:

```
lifeProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.lifeProgressBar);
lifeProgressBar.setMax(4);
lifeProgressBar.setProgress(4);
```

When recreating the activity, those lines are being called again. Even putting a breakpoint I can see that the progress is 4, **but the ProgressBar is being displayed empty**, the same as before recreating the activity.

I tried with invalidate, postinvalidate, etc... not worked.

How to solve this?

Comment: Try this:    lifeProgressBar.setProgress(0); then lifeProgressBar.setProgress(4);

Comment: @Opriday not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [recreate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#recreate()) documentation:

> ```
> public void recreate ()
> ```
>
> Cause this Activity to be recreated with a new instance. This results
>   in essentially the same flow as when the Activity is created due to a
>   configuration change -- the current instance will go through its
>   lifecycle to onDestroy() and a new instance then created after it.

Here are activity life cycle when activity got recreated:

`onSaveInstanceState()` // Save current progress of life progress bar (0 in your case)
`onDestroy()`
 
`onCreate()` // You fill full life progress bar
 
`onRestoreInstanceState()` // [**IMPORTANT**] Activity restores previous state and set progress of life progress bar to 0.

This is expected behavior of Android, if you need to fill full life progress bar after activity got recreated, then you need to do it in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lifeProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.lifeProgressBar);
    fillFullLifeProgressBar();
}

private void fillFullLifeProgressBar() {
    lifeProgressBar.setMax(4);
    lifeProgressBar.setProgress(4);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Fill full life progress bar here.
    fillFullLifeProgressBar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recreating your activity like this will work for you.

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```